# Implement Java Project with JPA,JDBC using Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc

I have a java project which works with JDBC(as singleton) and MySQL server.
I converted the project to JPA project and implemented JPA class with entire entities from the same MySQL server. I'd like to use Spring API in order to configure whether to use JDBC or JPA what is the best way to do that? let say i will configure both as bean in the spring configuration file. what next?how should I handle the code to work once with JPA and once with JDBC.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I was asked to implement both technologies.  by using Spring I shall choose which one of them I'd like to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to abstract your DAO layer. You provide an interface like the following :

```
public interface Dao {
      void persist(E entity);
      void remove(E entity);
      E findById(K id);
}
```

The provide an abstract implementation of it as

```
public abstract class JpaDao implements Dao {
    protected Class entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    //so on.. and delegate calls to entity manager.
```

Now provide another DAO implementation that depends up on your JDBC DB manager singleton.

```
public abstract class JDBCDao implements Dao {
        protected MyDBManager dbManager;
        //delegate calls to db manager
```

Now implement all your DAOs specific to functionalities; each for JPA base class and JDBC Base class.
Implement an [abstract factory](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=128) which can create various kinds of DAOs for you depending on whether you need the JPA family or JDBC family.

Once that is done, define your daos using factory such as :

```
<!-- factory instance to create JPA family of DAOs -->
<bean id="myJPADaoFactory"
  class="AbstractDAOFactory"> 
  <!--other init  parameters specific to JPA -->

<!-- factory instance to create JDBC family of DAOs -->
<bean id="myJDBCaoFactory"
  class="AbstractDAOFactory"> 
  <!-- other init  parameters specific to JDBC -->
```

Now define your DAO beans as :

```
<bean id="exampleDaoBean"
      factory-bean="#{systemProperties.dao.config}"
      factory-method="createExampleDAO"/>
```

Note that the factory-bean is a dynamic parameter to be loaded from `System.properties`

When you launch your application pass the switch using parameter `dao.config` using `-D` argument to the JVM.

So, for example when you want to use JPA based DAOs you would run java as :
`java -Ddao.config="myJPADaoFactory" <Your App>`

If you are using an application server, you need to edit its specific configuration file to pass the -D parameter. For example, in tomcat this can be set via `CATALINA_OPTS` variable. It largely depends on what App server you are using.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already have an interface for both JPA and JDBC.  your answer is great and simple. 
I think to import from spring configuration file and Cast it to the interface.
Once i have the instance I just call the methods.
its exactly what you answered!
Thanks!

Comment: what is the dao.config file?? is it part of Spring?

Comment: No dao.config is just a property key. Its value you are passing from java command '-D' parameter. as `-Ddao.config="myJPADaoFactory"`

Comment: I dont run my app with CMD.  does it still matter ?

Comment: what about the idea : when using Spring API -> 

 ApplicationContext theContext =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("any name.xml");
        
        My Interface obj  = (My Interface)theContext.getBean("JPA Manager");
        My Interface obj2  = (My Interface)theContext.getBean("JDBC Manager");